# How to rewrite a state machine in a clearer style?

Tags: python, state-machine

I am interacting with an external device, and I have to issue certain commands in order. Sometimes I have to jump back and redo steps. Pseudocode (the actual code has more steps and jumps):

```
enter_update_mode()  # step 1
success = start_update()
if not success:
    retry from step 1
leave_update_mode()
```

How do I handle this the cleanest way? What I did for now is to define an enum, and write a state machine. This works, but is pretty ugly:

```
class Step(Enum):
    ENTER_UPDATE_MODE = 1
    START_UPDATE = 2
    LEAVE_UPDATE_MODE = 3
    EXIT = 4

def main():
    next_step = Step.ENTER_UPDATE_MODE

    while True:
        if next_step == Step.ENTER_UPDATE_MODE:
            enter_update_mode()
            next_step = Step.START_UPDATE
        elif next_step == Step.START_UPDATE:
            success = start_update()
            if success:
                next_step = Step.LEAVE_UPDATE_MODE
            else:
                next_step = Step.ENTER_UPDATE_MODE
        ....
```

I can imagine an alternative would be to just call the functions nested. As long as this is only a few levels deep, it should not be a problem:

```
def enter_update_mode():
    # do stuff ...
    # call next step:
    perform_update()

def perform_update():
    # ...
    # call next step:
    if success:
        leave_update_mode()
    else:
        enter_update_mode()
```

I have looked into the [python-statemachine](https://pypi.org/project/python-statemachine/) module, but it seems to be there to *model* state machines. You can define states and query which state it is in, and you can attach behavior to states. But that is not what I'm looking for. I am looking for a way to write the behavior code in a very straightforward, imperative style, like you would use for pseudocode or instructions to a human.

There is also a module to add `goto` to Python, but I think it is a joke and would not like to use it in production :-).

Notes:

- This code is *synchronous*, meaning it is a terminal app or a separate thread. Running concurrently with other code would be an added complication. If a solution allows that (e.g. by using `yield`) that would be a bonus, but not neccessary.
- I left out a lot of retry logic. A step may be only retried a certain number of times.
- Releated discussion of explicit state machine vs. imperative style: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/147182/62069